# Is there a way to refresh all components in React Native on resize of the window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am developing a web app using React Native and designed the style of the components to depend on the width and height of the window. I would like these components to update instantly as soon as the user resizes the window, so they depend on the new width and height.

So far I could only make the update in a form of a window refresh using JavaScript code, but that's not what I want.

Anyone knows how to achieve that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useWindowDimensions` hook to get notified of screen size changes. Documentation [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions).

```
function App() {
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();

  useEffect(
    () => {
      // Update your UI here
    },
    [width, height]
  );

  return (
    // ...
  );
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that without writing new code that updates the UI? Right now in my code the component's appearance is determined by React's StyleSheet

Comment: Not really, `StyleSheet` is not meant to be reactive since it assigns unique IDs to each property and only sends these over the bridge instead of the whole style object. You could however build a very simple hook abstraction over `StyleSheet`. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @emeraldsanto could you please update your answer to reflect what you mentioned in your comment?